# Using Tokens in SQL Job Setup SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, cluster-computing

OS: Windows 2008 Server R2 |
SQL Version: SQL Server 2008 R2 |
Env: Clustered (Failover)

I have SSIS packages that are stored in the local file system and the "Packages" folder that contains all the packages is "shared".

In Windows 2003 Servers I use \127.0.0.1\Packages\PackageName.dtsx in the job to execute the package. But in Windows 2008 server 127.0.0.1 had been blocked and I will have to use the host name \ServerName\Packages\Packagename.dtsx.

In order to avoid this I tried to use \$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))\Packages\PackageName.dtsx. This is working fine in a single node machine but what will the token return in Clustered env? (SRVR token resolves to the Machine name which has the SQL server installed)

Also any other option on accessing the file share in Windows 2008 Server (Clustered) without the hostname will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested The usage of $(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR)) token in the job steps and it works perfectly. This will be a solution if you are facing issues with the loop back address (127.0.0.1) in Windows 2008 Server or you are faced with multiple data centers that share the same code.

The token always resolves to the machine that has the SQL Server installed. In my case it is a clustered Server with 2 nodes (Active/Passive).